# CSS/Bootstrap Responsive design paragraph

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am developing website based on Bootstrap template.
Here is link: http://pixelslab.pl/ly/
I just have trouble with paragraphs in the middle - they are overlaping in strange way.
Any idea how to fix it?

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp9yt.png)

Comment: You need to include some HTML and CSS snippets to get an answer about this. It's impossible to work out what is going wrong with the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make them work as expected, you should set your default `line-height` to normal in a certain breakpoint like `767px`. You should also apply `flex-direction: column;` to the parent element in order to get better results. So the result should be something like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .elementor-text-wrap .section {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .section p {
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: normal;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fixed height is causing this... change your CSS in the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px){
    .elementor-text-wrap .section
    {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-top: inherit    
    }
}
```